# Disable enforce utf8 in a redmine form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, redmine

I have a redmine installation running fine. I have an issue to disable the utf-8 enforcement tag when doing searches. This is because on my network there is a url policy check that will prevent me from opening the url containing the utf-8 enforcement parameter.

So I went to `/usr/share/redmine/app/views/issues/index.html.erb` and changed this line:

```
<%= form_tag({ :controller => 'issues', :action => 'index', :project_id => @project },
            :method => :get, :id => 'query_form') do %>
```

to this

```
<%= form_tag({ :controller => 'issues', :action => 'index', :project_id => @project },
            :method => :get, :id => 'query_form', :enforce_utf8 => false) do %>
```

but the utf8 enforcement parameter shows up

What am I doing wrong? Can I disable it on a global base?